# Checking all connections on Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark, windows-firewall, sysinternals

I want to check all outbound/inbound connections when my pc is (apparently) idle and possibly permit/deny selectively each of them as soon as they occur. Unfortunately it seems not possible on Windows 7 without additional tools. So I did the following:

- On Windows Firewall I've set Outbound Connections -> Block
- I enabled Windows Firewall logging
- I started TCPView

My purpose is to monitor all blocked connection and understand which services and background applications require them.

Firewall log shows blocked IP connections together with destination IP address, but doesn't show the application requiring this connection. TCPView instead (and `netstat` as well, which I guess provides the same output) doesn't show this blocked connection at all. How to get the PID of the connection then?

Just to make things more confused, Wireshark shows DNS queries and responses despite these being reported as DROP in Windows Firewall, and not reported at all in TCPView. Why?

Comment: I use this free software to control all outbound connections >>>>>https://www.binisoft.org/wfc

Comment: Wow @Moab!  What a great tool that I wasn't even looking for! :)  Thanks!